# Angular 2 mouseenter/mouseleave event triggered multiple times

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

In the following code example:

[plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/WsdbjAechGxe0iZ587Xw/)

I am trying to show a modal when the mouse enter into a button and to hide the modal when the mouse leave the button, however, if the mouse is being move aroud "inside" the button, the modal is triggered multiple times. Which does not make sense.

Is there another event I can use to avoid this weird behavior? I tried mouseover but the same issue happens.

Comment: I'm not sure it's your problem. Your problem is that when the modal is shown, it goes over your html, meaning that your mouse actually leaves the button to be on the modal. You can see that by putting a console.log in your show function.

Comment: yes, you are right :(

Comment: I know, I'm always right. Jokes apart, since bootstrap provides tons of ways to handle their modal, why would you control it with a component ? Just use it like theey want you to use it !

Comment: It seems you are right again. hehe, well, I was trying to consolidate all the logic within a component and manage it with angular events. I tried adding .modal{ pointer-events:none }' and it worked (it cancels all the events in the modal), but I would like to see other solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you more, I'm not a big fan of bootstrap with angular 2. Try around and see what works best for you !